# can't access on local database when app is terminated

Tags: flutter

I'm using `sqflite 1.2.0 and`flutter_background_geolocation`

and user headless mode with `flutter_background_geolocation` that make me listen on location and work as I expected but I'm try compare current location buy location that saved in local database I'm facing this issues just If i closed the app but if opening or in background it's work

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

my headless code is

```
void headlessTask(bg.HeadlessEvent headlessEvent) async {
  print('[BackgroundGeolocation HeadlessTask]: $headlessEvent');
  // Implement a 'case' for only those events you're interested in.
  switch(headlessEvent.name) {
    case bg.Event.LOCATION:
      bg.Location location = headlessEvent.event;
      await LocationListenerHelper.onLocation(location);
      print('- Location: $location');
      break;
    case bg.Event.MOTIONCHANGE:
      bg.Location location = headlessEvent.event;
      await LocationListenerHelper.onLocation(location);
      print('- Location: $location');
      break;
  }
}

void main() async {
  runApp(delegate, MyApp());

  if(Platform.isAndroid){
    // Register your headlessTask:
    bg.BackgroundGeolocation.registerHeadlessTask(headlessTask);
  }
}
```

onLocation method code is

```
  static Future<void> onLocation(bg.Location location) async {

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> objects = await SqLiteHelper.query(table:'locations');

    if (objects == null || objects.length == 0) {return;}

    print('[new Location listen] ....');

   }

  /*
    init and open database 
  */
  Future<void> databaseInitAndOpen() async {
    // await destroy();
    String path = await databasePath();
    // open the database
    _database = await sqlite.openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (
        sqlite.Database db,
        int version,
      ) async {
        await db.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE suggestions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lid Text , title TEXT, counter INTEGER , updatedAt Text)');
        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE itemslocations (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, intId INTEGER,type Text, parentId TEXT null, objectId TEXT,lid TEXT, title TEXT, countOfItem INTEGER null, latitude Text, longitude TEXT, radius INTEGER)');
      },
    );

  }

  /* 
    get or query for get data from table
  */
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query({table, where,orderBy,limit}) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> query =
        await _database.query(table, where: where, orderBy: orderBy, limit: limit);
    return query;
  }
```

Comment: hey, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @BillyMahmood did you find a way?